# Antiderivative of a piecewise function

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, piecewise-continuity

I’m trying to solve the IVP $y’=\dfrac{f(y)}{1+x^4}$ with the initial condition $y(0)=(0)$. Here $$f(y)=|y|\ln|y|$$ for $y \neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Using separation of variables I arrive at $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{f(y)}{1+x^4} \iff \int \dfrac{dy}{f(y)}=\int \dfrac{1}{1+x^4}dx.$$ Is there any way to calculate $$\int \dfrac{1}{f(y)}dy?$$
Or is there a simpler way to solve this ODE?

Comment: note that, the intergral is `\int dx/(1+x^4)`, not `\int (1+x^4)dx`  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int+dx%2F%281%2Bx%5E4%29

Comment: @Black Mild You’re right! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\int \dfrac{1}{f(y)}dy= \int \dfrac{1}{|y|\ln |y|}dy=\text{sgn}(y)\ln (\ln |y|)
$$

Comment: More precisely, $\text{sgn}(y)\ln\left|\ln|y|\right|$ would be better.

Comment: @MH.Lee - Certainly, thanks